# How to find the current user's system theme color using Python?

Tags: python, windows, colors, pyqt, pyqt5

Does anyone know how to get the current user's current system theme color in Windows using Python?

[image: Windows theme color]

I'm making a GUI in PyQt5 and want to change the color of the frame according to the system theme color.

Comment: Do you mean [QPalette](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html)?

Comment: @musicamante No, I basically want the current user.. user theme color (as shown in the image) using python.

Comment: with `palette = QPalette()` (which is the same as [`QApplication.palette()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#palette)) you *do* get the palette for the current user, which includes all the colors used for drawing the UI and based on the current system settings.

Comment: @musicamante That's not always true. Some styles use the native theme engine for drawing certain elements, so sometimes the palette might not reflect what's displayed on screen. I think Windows is affected in that way, but I can't actually test it myself.

Comment: @ekhumoro yes, that's right, but that's the only source of system palette available from Qt in any case.